# How to submit Formik when button submit outside tag formik in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, formik

[image]

I have a component composition as above, the box with brown color is the parent and has a blue child box as the formix container and the right side with the green color is the container where the button is placed. is it possible to submit a form with a button outside the formix tag?
I read the documentation but still not found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can handle it using the `Formik` tag `innerRef` reference. I added a working demo pls find [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-0li2tv).

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import "./helper.css";

const App = () => {
  const formRef = useRef();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (formRef.current) {
      formRef.current.handleSubmit();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Formik
        innerRef={formRef}
        initialValues={{ email: "" }}
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
          email: Yup.string().email().required("Required")
        })}
      >
        {(props) => {
          const {
            values,
            touched,
            errors,
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit
          } = props;
          return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <label htmlFor="email" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                Email
              </label>
              <input
                id="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                type="text"
                value={values.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                className={
                  errors.email && touched.email
                    ? "text-input error"
                    : "text-input"
                }
              />
              {errors.email && touched.email && (
                <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
              )}
            </form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: This answer is not valid for TypeScript. The type of innerRef doesn't match useRef()

Comment: Hi, @Organic If you are using the latest Formik version then you do not need to use `innerRef`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am using v2.1.5, it's not the very latest but will upgrade if the new method is more elegant. How does it work now, can you point me to the right docs?